# How to Access Remote USB Smartcard during RDP

Tags: dll, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, smartcard, rdp

[My set up]

RDP Client (Win7)   ------------------RDP------------------------> Remote Server (Win2k8R2) with SmartCard

I've found countless answers that would suggest this is not possible. Alot of answers indicate that RDP was designed this way for security. The smartcards are locked which do not allow the device to be seen when connecting remotely with Remote desktop connection (RDP).

However I've found a useful link which appears to work for some but not all.

http://lifayk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/windows-smart-card-subsystem-and-remote.html

The guide shows how it's possible (by editing the winSCard.dll - forcing the function to return local user not remote which allows the smartcard to be seen remotely) but lacks the detail for beginners like myself. I tried using the latest patch linked on the site however it fails to work on Windows Server 2008 R2.

My questions following the article are;

- How do I edit winSCard.dll without a hex editor? (So I can see functions/methods) I've tried using Reflector however when I opened winSCard.dll it said not .NET file.
- There was mention of turning off Windows File Protection - This appears to have changed, does simply changing ownership of the system32 folder and copying the new winSCard.dll file over allow the new .dll to work? (after restarting the smartcard service)

This is all new to me and any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Use `windbg` from the Windows SDK debug tools. The function you are looking for is `InTSRedirectModeWithContext`.

Also this might help: http://lifayk.blogspot.ro/2012/07/windows-smart-card-subsystem-and-remote.html