# Using Server USB SmartCard reader

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

i'm running a Terminal Server (Windows Server 2012 R2)

And have a big problem accessing smart cards (in my setting German "Gesundheitskarten") on our Terminal Server in RDP Sessions. These cards are not used to provide login to a program, but to transmit data like Insurance Number, Street, Postal Code etc... to our Database.

The Problem is, that the Smart Card reader (https://www.identiv.com/products/smart-card-readers/contact-smart-card-readers/utrust-2700-r-contact-smart-card-reader) which is attached to the Server (via USB) is showing in the device manager but not accessible in an RDP Session. The manufacturers test programm says that the Smart Card Ressource Manager is NOT Running (which isn't true) which indicates the the device is not accessible. 
When i logon directly on the server (without RDP) the reader works fine. (Logged in as Admin or User)

I would try to connect the reader to the client device, but there a numerous reasons against it. Just to name a few: We have all sorts of clients (Mac/Android/iOs/Windows) who need access to the reader when they are near our front desk. Mobile Devices and Macs do not support SmartCard redirection. Also the Application which reads the Cards is unknown to support the redirection setup.
(Just for clarification, i don't want to give our users direct physical access to the Server - they use the app via RDP or mainly via Remote Resources)

Is there any way to map/bind the USB Smart Card Reader to a user also in an RDP Session which is connected to the Server? Is there any group policy setting i forgot?

Comment: Not sure if this is any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375364/how-to-access-remote-usb-smartcard-during-rdp?rq=1

Comment: hey James! thanks for your reply! sadly this guy had the same problem... but with server 2008 - and he also didn't get a reply that would help in my situation - they suggest a workaround with extra software (which costs a lot to license)

Comment: Unfortunately I think you want something that's not common place. Having (encrypted by nature) smart card data passed between interactive user sessions would be a security risk to most places.

Answer (score 1):

You have to crack WinSCard.dll and SCardSvr.dll.

Refer to this page: http://lifayk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/windows-smart-card-subsystem-and-remote.html

I had tested the method and it works on Windows 2012 R2 Standard and Dataceneter.

Comment: Wow! Looks promising and can possibly help a lot of people.